# How to tell PhpStorm that function argument is file path

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

In PhpStorm (and other JetBrains IDE), is it possible to make function attributes as file / resource path?

E.g. in this function:

```php
function mix($file): string
{
  // check mix maninfest for $file and return path from mix manifest
  return $fire_path_with_cachebuster;
}
```

I'd like PHP to suggest files in the project as I define `$file` attribute when calling mix function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only manually for the moment, when calling that function . And it's a temp injection (for a session) so it's not convenient:

```php
mix('')
```

- Place caret inside the string parameter
- Use <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> (or via light bulb icon) to bring the Quick Fix / Intentions menu (on some Keymaps it might be different one)
- Use "Inject language or reference" option
  [image]
- Then choose "File Reference" entry there (just start typing to filter the list).
  [image]

The result:
[image]

---

Hopefully they will implement the following tickets for a permanent solution:

- Using `#[Language]` PHP attribute **at the function declaration**: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-56996
- Or in-place via PHPDoc-like comment (before the parameter **when calling that function**): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-20028

Watch those tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress (and hopefully speed it up by bringing dev's attention).

Comment: Ah, gotta upvote those tickets then. Thanks!

Comment: It's available now as `// language=file-reference`

Comment: Or `#[Language('file-reference')]` attribute (alas, sadly it doesn't seem to do anything)

Answer (score 0):

Like [LazyOne](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66335054/7824123) stated, there is currently no way to declare a parameter as being a file reference.

However, you can get a more permanent File Reference "injection" by [mis]using `__DIR__`.

PhpStorm considers a string mixed with the `__DIR__` constant to be a file path:

[image]

It isn't perfect as it depends on what directory you are currently located in. If you only want the filename passed to your method, you can wrap the string in `basename`, or handle that from within your method.

```php
echo mix(basename(__DIR__ . '/slack_bot.php'));
```